# BookshelfJS Relationship - hasMany

Tags: node.js, orm, bookshelf.js

I'm using BookshelfJS as my ORM. I have 3 models.

```
TripHistory
user_id
route_id

Route
id
name

Users
id
name
```

From my user model, I have a relationship

```
trips() {
  return this.hasMay(TripHistory)
}
```

And the TripHistory has a relationship  like

```
route() {
  return this.belongsTo(Route)
}
```

The problem here is, when I try to get the trip History, I want to get just the route name. Running

```
 withRelated: ['trips.route']
```

returns

```
"trips": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "user_id": 1,
            "route_id": 1,
            "driver_id": 1,
            "trip_id": 1,
            "created_at": "2017-08-09T16:46:34.000Z",
            "updated_at": "2017-08-09T16:46:34.000Z",
            "route": {
                "id": 1,
                "pickup": "Fadeyi",
                "destination": "Jibowu",
                "departure_time": "6:00",
                "time_of_day": "AM",
                "day_of_week": "MON",
                "fair": 500,
                "created_at": "2017-08-09T16:21:58.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2017-08-09T16:21:58.000Z",
                "pickup_coordinate": "6.528482899999999, 3.3628242",
                "destination_coordinate": "6.5177977, 3.3678641"
            }
        },
```

But I really will love only the route object

```
"trips": [
        {

                "id": 1,
                "pickup": "Fadeyi",
                "destination": "Jibowu",
                "departure_time": "6:00",
                "time_of_day": "AM",
                "day_of_week": "MON",
                "fair": 500,
                "created_at": "2017-08-09T16:21:58.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2017-08-09T16:21:58.000Z",
                "pickup_coordinate": "6.528482899999999, 3.3628242",
                "destination_coordinate": "6.5177977, 3.3678641"

        },
```

Any idea how I can fix this from the model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my own problem. Here is the right solution

```
trips() {
  return this.hasMany('Route')
    .through('TripHistory', 'id', 'user_id', 'route_id');
}
```

I hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a function to the `TripHistory`  model with definition like below...

```
fetchWithOnlyRouteRelationship: async function() {

        const result = await this.fetchAll( withRelated: ['trips.route'] );
        return result['route'];
},
```

then refer to it in your service / controller like so..

```
new TripHistory({id : bar }).fetchWithOnlyRouteRelationship();
```

Comment: Yes, please ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined```. Did you try your solutions out on a project or something?